# Procurar o ano em que o total de clientes (soma) foi maior

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

Estou a usar sqlite, e tenho uma tabela do tipo:

```
year | clients    
---- | -------                                                            
2000 | 1                                                                              
2000 | 2  
1999 | 3                                                                      
1999 | 5  
2000 | 4                                                                      
1999 | 6
```

Isto é apenas um exemplo. Quero encontrar o ano em que o total de clientes foi maior.

O melhor que consegui fazer foi separar por cada ano, somar os clientes, e apresentar todos os anos com a respectiva soma. Mas não sei como apresentar apenas o ano em que foi maior.

Quero apresentar o ano e total de clientes. Ou seja:

```
1999 | 14
```

Eu usei:

```sql
select year, sum(clients) from table group by year;
```

Já tentei também

```sql
select year, max(sum(clients)) from table group by year;
```

Comment: Este é [pt.so], as perguntas e respostas aqui precisam ser em **português**. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e traduzi-la.

Comment: Já está traduzido. Obrigado pela formatação do texto, sou um nabo nisto xD

Comment: Você pode utilizar a cláusula LIMIT:  `select year, sum(clients) from table group by year order by sum(clients) DESC limit 1;`

Comment: Tranquilo. Existe um [guia de formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) que você pode usar sempre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O primeiro select está correto segundo o exemplo de resultado que você pôs na pergunta.

Se o nome da tabela é realmente `table` (aliás, o nome é péssimo) você deve escapar o nome usando *backticks* porque esta é uma palavra reservada. Ou seja, é preciso usar `` `table` `` ao invés de `table`.

Se precisa apresentar apenas o primeiro resultado, use `limit 1` ao final da *query*. Neste caso, é uma boa ideia forçar a ordenação pela coluna em que é feita a soma de clientes.

```sql
select year, sum(clients) as soma 
from `table`
group by year 
order by soma desc
limit 1
```

[Veja funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/472da6/1).

Comment: Claro, table era só um exemplo. Obrigado pela ajuda! No entanto, o primeiro select apresenta os dois anos e respetivas somas. Não é isso que quero. Quero apresentar apenas o 1999 (visto que a soma é maior).

Comment: Não foi isso que você disse na pergunta (no seu exemplo de saída esperada mostra os dois anos). De qualquer forma é só adicionar `LIMIT 1` ao final da query.

Comment: @Alcachofra Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Tem razão. Já atualizei a pergunta também. Obrigado. Genial a resposta! Ou então eu é que sou um nabo ahahah